# Flutter web, add a dynamic prefix path to all routes

Tags: flutter, dart

Having a flutter web app, with a couple of screens each defined with a route name. The app will be hosted on `blabla.host.com mainly`

I have a couple of requirements..

1. The first path segment is dynamic and mandatory, which specifies the behavior of the app, ex: `blabla.host.com/prop1/`, `blabla.host.com/prop2/`, let's call it dynamicWord (`blabla.host.com/:dynamicWord/`)
2. So the first path segment will be treated as dynamicWord, rest is the route name.
3. Routing to a screen should be done by `Navigator.of().pushNamed($routeName)` and the browser url path would be `blabla.host.com/dynamicWord/$routeName`
4. So in short:
   `blabla.host.com/dynamicWord/` will open the entry screen (splash screen),
   `blabla.host.com/dynamicWord/chat_screen` will open the chat screen
   `blabla.host.com/dynamicWord/setting_screen` will open the setting screen
5. Think of this $dynamicWord as base_href as if the app is deployed to `blabla.host.com/dynamicWord/`

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use go_router for dynamic routing https://pub.dev/packages/go_router